# Delete a folder named ~ in unix

Tags: unix, delete-file

Under my home directory I see a directory named `~`. I guess I must have accidentally copied my home directory somehow.

Anyway, it's eaten up all my space and I'd like to remove it but obviously just running `rm -r ~` will delete the entire contents of my home directory.

Any idea how to delete that `~` directory without any damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `\` before it: `rm -rf \~`.

Answer (score 1):

Escape it so the shell doesn't expand the tilde. Any of these will do:

```
rm -r '~'
rm -r \~
rm -r ~/'~'
rm -r ~/\~
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `rm -rf \~`
The `\` escape key should stop you from deleting you're home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make an `ls | grep -v <other files>` statement, which ignores all the other files, so that it only lists the file with that weird name.
Then you do:

```
rm $(ls | grep -v <other files>)
```

Obviously, you need to be careful first to test this thoroughly.